# Should componentDidMount run from connectStateResults?

Tags: reactjs, algolia, infinite-carousel, instantsearch

I'm trying to create an infinite [siema](https://github.com/pawelgrzybek/siema/blob/master/README.md) carousel using algolia's [instantsearch in react](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/connectors/), but I don't think the connectors behave like React components.  Should I expect componentDidMount to be called here?  Suggestions?  Ideas?

```
class ActorsClass extends connectStateResults {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var { searchState, searchResults } = props;
    this.hasResults = searchResults && searchResults.nbHits !== 0;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount " + this.props.siema)
    this.siema = new Siema(this.props.siema);
  }

  prev = () => {
    this.siema.prev()
  };

  next = () => {
    this.siema.next()
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
        <div className="actors-container">
          <div xhidden={!this.hasResults}>
            <h1>Actors</h1>
            <InfiniteHits hitComponent={HitActors} />
          </div>
        <button onClick={this.prev}>Prev</button>
        <button onClick={this.next}>Next</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the connected component receives new props they are re-invoked. It means you can use `componentDidUpdate` hook for your use case.

You may be interested to use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). See the [docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computingderiveddata) for using selector.

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried componentDidUpdate as well - no success.  I'm not certain that the Algolia connector components call either or follow the usual React lifecycle.